# how to exit jenkins pipeline stage prematurely

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to create jenkins pipeline to take DB export using a script. In order to keep my DB up, i need to keep refreshing it, as DB goes down after inactivity. So i created a simple spring project called "keep-alive" which hit a db query under nohup. both DB export and poll happens in same stage. export which ultimately completes, keep-alive service keeps going on indefinitely and i am not able to come out of the stage to turn my machine down.

below is my pipeline . what needs to be changed, so that once

```
sudo python3 export_new.py -cl ${CB_HOST}
```

completes execution, stage should be exited and post part should execute which stops the machine and sends email.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    parameters {
        string (name: 'MACHINE_INSTANCE_ID', defaultValue: '', description: 'AWS EC2 Instance ID ', trim: true)
        string (name: 'MACHINE_IP', defaultValue: '', description: 'AWS EC2 IP ', trim: true)
        string (name: 'CB_HOST', description: 'host to backup e.g. "http://somehost.com" ', trim: true)
    }
     stages{

        stage('Start AWS EC2 Instance') {
         steps {
                 sh label: 'Start AWS EC2 Instance', returnStatus: false, script: '''#!/bin/sh

                   aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids ${MACHINE_INSTANCE_ID}
                   aws ec2 wait instance-running --instance-ids ${MACHINE_INSTANCE_ID}
                   aws ec2 wait instance-status-ok --instance-ids ${MACHINE_INSTANCE_ID}

                   echo "EC2 Instance ${MACHINE_INSTANCE_ID} successfully started!!"
                 '''
           }
        }

        stage('Perform Backup') {
              steps {
                script {
                 sh label: 'Perform Backup', returnStatus: false, script: '''#!/bin/sh
                       ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /var/lib/jenkins/pem ec2-user@${MACHINE_IP} 'bash -c' "'
                         
                         sudo su -
                         cd /home/ubuntu/keep-alive
                         echo "starting keep alive service.."

                         sudo nohup java -jar keep-alive-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --places.dbHost=${CB_HOST} &

                         sleep 5

                         cd /home/ubuntu
                         echo "-- Running backup for ${CB_HOST} env"
                        sudo python3 export_new.py -cl ${CB_HOST}
                       '"
                     '''
              }
           }
         }
     }

     post {
         always {
           emailext attachLog: false,  mimeType: 'text/plain', subject: "export build ",
                 body: "Job completed..\nSee logs for more info:\n${env.BUILD_URL}/console",
                 to: 'abc.ec@xyz.com'

           sh label: 'Stop AWS EC2 Instance', script: '''#!/bin/sh

             aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids ${MACHINE_INSTANCE_ID}
             aws ec2 wait instance-stopped --instance-ids ${MACHINE_INSTANCE_ID}
             echo "EC2 Instance ${MACHINE_INSTANCE_ID} successfully stopped!!"
           '''
         }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the process ID of the `nohup` command and kill it after taking the backup. Something like below.

```
nohup my_command > my.log 2>&1 &
echo $! > save_pid.txt
# Run the backup
kill -9 `cat save_pid.txt`
exit 0
```

Comment: i tried same approach but i get save_pid.txt : no such file or directory. file is. present on location but still getting that error on jenkins. but if i follow same steps on ec2 machine directly it works.